# coloring parentheses and curly brackets in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I looked in the tool options of Rstudio and couldn't find a way to color either the curly brackets or the selection of curly brackets. With the dark theme that I am using is really hard to see where my closing or opening curly brackets or parentheses are located on a long script. Is there a way to color or make these blink when selected? See a pic below:

[image]

Comment: If you're using a custom rstudio theme, you can set the colour of the highlighted brace by changing ".ace_bracket". Further discussion on this topic here: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/7599

Comment: I am using one of the built-in Rstudio themes. I read about it but not sure how to implement your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a custom rstudio theme called "atom One Dark". You can download it from https://github.com/tkrabel/rstudio_atom_theme/blob/master/atom.rstheme. I was able to change the colour of the highlighted brace by following these steps:

1. Download the "atom.rstheme" text file from https://github.com/tkrabel/rstudio_atom_theme/blob/master/atom.rstheme (or any custom rstheme file; see e.g. https://github.com/mkearney/rstudiothemes)
2. Open the file ("atom.rstheme") in a text editor
3. Change:

```
.ace_bracket {
  margin: 0 !important;
  border: 0 !important;
  background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5);
}
```

to:

```
.ace_bracket {
  margin: 0 !important;
  border: 0 !important;
  background-color: rgba(73, 204, 37, 0.5);
}
```

4. Also change:

```
.ace_marker-layer .ace_bracket {
  margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
  border: 1px solid #4B4E55
}
```

to:

```
.ace_marker-layer .ace_bracket {
  margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
  border: 1px solid #25c235
}
```

(These edits change the highlighted brace colour from grey to bright green; choose your hex code / rgb code accordingly)

5. Then, restart R and reload the edited theme file. To do this, click on `Tools> Global Options> Appearance` and select a theme that isn't "One Dark", then add the 'updated' "One Dark" theme file (`Tools> Global Options> Appearance> Add` and select the "atom.rstheme" from the file explorer)
6. Restart R and you have coloured highlighting, e.g.

[image: image.png]

If you're on macOS, your default themes are stored in `/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/resources/themes`; you can also copy one of these files and make the same changes to the '.ace_bracket' parameter e.g. copy `vibrant_ink.rstheme` to `updated_vibrant_ink.rstheme`, edit the '.ace_bracket' colors in "updated_vibrant_ink.rstheme" and then add the theme as above (`Tools>Global Options>Appearance>Add`).

If you're on Windows, apparently the default themes are stored at `C:\Users\<your user account>\Documents\.R\rstudio\themes` (re [this article](https://www.rstudio.com/blog/rstudio-ide-custom-theme-support/)).

Comment: Great!!! Can you show the steps on how to import it into R studio?

Comment: From the main menu, click >Tools >Global Options >Appearance >Add (down the bottom of the screen). I'll edit my answer when I get a chance

Comment: Ok, Do I save those two commands into a file or copy and paste once I get to the appearance? When I click on Add, it takes me to file explorer. Do I need to put those two commands at the bottom or your post into a notepad file?

Comment: Sorry for the delay @Salvador, I've updated my answer; do these steps solve your problem?

Comment: Once I download the theme and make the changes in notepad. Can I save the new theme with the changes anywhere? What do I call the newly created file...anyname will work or I need to give it a specific theme name?